# IO error when accessing app.config from thread

Tags: thread-safety, app-config, read-write

I'm trying to write to my app.config from a thread using **Task.Run(()=> method)** but I'm getting an IO error on line 2 in the method below

**"System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'WpfApplication1.exe.Config' because it is being used by another process.'"**

```
private static void UpdateCustomConfigSection(string sectionName, string key, string val)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile); //Error happens here

            XmlNode selectSingleNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode($"//{sectionName}/add[@key='{key}']");
            if (selectSingleNode != null && selectSingleNode.Attributes != null)
            {
               selectSingleNode.Attributes["value"].Value = val;
            }

            xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);
        }
```

I assume this is happening because the main application thread is reading from the file and is blocking the thread from accessing it. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For work with app.config you should use [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx).
See example below:

```
    private static void UpdateCustomConfigSection(string key, string val)
    {
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = val;
        configuration.Save();
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
```

But if the problem is different thread you can use [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            UpdateCustomConfigSection(sectionName,key, val);
        });
```

In this case `UpdateCustomConfigSection` should be invokes in UI thread regardless of where   Dispatcher.Invoke construction calls

Comment: Yes I am using configurationManager to update my AppSettings section but as you can see by my method name I'm trying to update a custom section outside of appSettings. Also... this works fine when I'm not trying to use it from a different thread.

Comment: If the problem  exists only on different thread I can suggest use
**Dispatcher.Invoke**
.All code which you put inside Dispatcher.Invoke will execute in main UI wpf thread. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I updated answer and add example with   Dispatcher.Invoke